# How to put a margin-right in sidebar using CSS properly in Django>

Tags: css, django

I tried to put margin to separate text and icon using this code

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css'%}">
    <!-- <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="{% static '/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css'%}" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="{% static 'fontawesomefree/js/all.min.js' %}"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <header>Menu</header>
        <a href="#" class="active"><i class="fas fa-qrcode"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-link"></i><span>Data Entry</span></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-stream"></i><span>List</span></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code

```
a.active,a:hover{
    border-left: 5px solid #019321;
    color: #bfeb74;
  }

.sidebar a i{
    margin-right: 300px;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmktL.png)

It should look like this. Same code that put in codepen.io. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbb5F.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add padding to the span.

```
span { padding-left: 20px; }
```

Comment: This works. But i still can't figure out why this code doesnt work in django   .sidebar  a i {
    margin-right: 300px;
}

Comment: I would recommend you to use classes. Just use `.fas { prop: value }` class and it will overwrite default properties.

Comment: This should be more specific otherwise it could affect other spans in the page. You could write `.sidebar span` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can change like this:

instead of this:

```
.sidebar a i{
    margin-right: 300px;
```

Try this:

```
.sidebar > a > i {
    margin-right: 300px;
```

This will work perfect.

Note: Add pixel value how much you want

Comment: This works really well in codepen.io and xampp. but doesn't work in django.

Comment: This should work in django too. Try to restart your server

Answer (score 0):

i think its because you apply margin in a inline tag(?)

```
a.active,a:hover{
    border-left: 5px solid #019321;
    color: #bfeb74;
  }

.sidebar a i {
   margin: 300px;
}

.sidebar a * {
    display: block;
}
```